# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (jpa 2.0)

Tags: jpa

When I try to delete a row from the database, I get this error message:" Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pquino01db`.`ITINERARYTRAVELLER_FLIGHTENTITY`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ITINERARYTRAVELLER_FLIGHTENTITY_flights_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`flights_ID`) REFERENCES `FLIGHTENTITY` (`ID`))"

```
@Entity
public class itineraryTraveller implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String departureLocation;
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date departureDate;
private String arrivalLocation;
private double cost;
private char status;
private ArrayList<String> stops;
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
private ArrayList<flightEntity> flights;
private String stopPrint;
private String userName;
private int iden;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
........
```

Can someone see the problem??? I think my @OneToMany annotation might be missing something, but dunno what

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "flightID", orphanRemoval = true)
private ArrayList<flightEntity> flights;
```

"flightID" must be equal to the variable name of the entity id of fligtEntity.

Documentation on mappedBy here [Bidirectional Relationships](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqj).

You can see what CascadeType.ALL means here [Cascade Operations and Relationships](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqm).

Comment: but I want unidirectional. An itineraryTraveller will contain a list of flights. and if I remove one flight from the flights table, I want that automatically all itineraryTravellers containing that flight to be deleted as well